# Energy-dependent Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Given some Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$, is it possible for it to depend on the energy  of the system, in a sense that the Schroedinger equation reads

$\mathcal{H}(E) {\psi} = E\psi$.

If so, what does that mean for the system described by the Hamiltonian? Instinctively I would've guessed that this is just a time-dependent system, as $E$ is related to the time $t$ via Fourier transform.

Comment: So you're basically asking if an operator can be a function of its eigenvalue?

Comment: An almost equivalent question would be "is it possible for the momentum operator to depend on momentum?".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, Hamiltonian IS by definition the energy of your quantum system.

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. You could probably also rephrase the question, and ask whether there are systems so that the (time-independent) Schroedinger equation becomes a nonlinear eigenvalue problem instead of a linear one, and whether a time-dependent system is an example of such a system.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not true. The reason is that, in order to have a conserved energy, the Heisenberg equation of motion
$$
\frac{dH}{dt}=0
$$
must hold. Indeed, quantum mechanics reflects the underlying Hamiltonian structure. Therefore, if I have a problem like
$$
H(t)|\psi\rangle=i\hbar\partial_t|\psi\rangle
$$
I can try to solve it using the adiabatic approximation but, in this case, I will look for an eigenvalue problem
$$
H(t)|n;t\rangle=E_n(t)|n;t\rangle,
$$
that is, I have to assume that the energy eigenvalues are time-dependent. This is perfectly consistent and gives a complete solution involving also a geometric Berry's phase. This is just another way to say that energy is not a good quantum number in such a case.